# React.js - Show/Hide dynamically generated elements from component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm generating form field elements using a component template importing an array of data. I want to be able to hide some of these elements and show them when some other's element's criteria has been met; this is fairly common in form fields, e.g. When you select item A, form field X appears, when you select item B, form field X is hidden.

I've read a fair bit on [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) on the React docs site but these examples don't really work for what I'm doing although the Preventing Component from Rendering section is close.

I [made a Codepen](https://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/qpmWVX?editors=1010) demoing my setup, what I want to do is show the second field if the criteria for the first field is met (in this example, the first field should have 5 characters entered). I've passed through a prop to set the initial hiding but how can I find that specific hidden element and unhide it?

```
// Field data
const fieldData = [{
    "type": "text",
    "label": "First",
    "name": "first",
    "placeholder": "Enter first name",
    "hidden": false
  }, {
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Surname",
    "name": "surname",
    "placeholder": "Enter surname",
    "hidden": true
  }];

  // Get form data
  class FormData extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        items: props.data
      };
    }

    render() {
      let els = this.state.items;

      return els.map((el, i) => {
          return <Input key={i} params={el} />
      });
    }
  }

  // Input builder
  class Input extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          // Keep state value
          this.state = {
              value: '',
              valid: false,
              hidden: this.props.params.hidden
          };

          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(e) {
          this.setState({
              value: e.target.value,
              valid: e.target.value.length < 5 ? false : true
          });
      }

      render() {
          // Element attributes
          const {type, label, name, placeholder, hidden} = this.props.params;
          const isValid = this.state.valid === true ? <span>Valid! Should show Surname field.</span> : <span>Not valid. Should hide Surname field.</span>;

          if (!hidden) {
            return (
            <div>
                {label ? <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label> : null}
                <input
                    type={type}
                    name={name}
                    placeholder={placeholder || null}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                {isValid}
            </div>
            );
          } else {
            return null;
          }
      }
  }

  // App
  class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <h1>Show/Hide test</h1>
            <p>What we want here is the surname to appear when firstname has a value (say, it has 5 characters) and hide surname when firstname doesn't.</p>
            <FormData data={fieldData} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


  ReactDOM.render(
      <form>
        <App />
      </form>,
      document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

Comment: I would give the fields some unique ids and raise the state 1 component up, to the form, where you would have an object of filed states by ids, i.e. `fieldStates: { '001': { value: '', valid: true, hidden: false }, '002': { ... } };`. This way I'd be able to check different fields validity in one component and change their visibility.

Comment: This is what I was thinking about... would I use the `key` property in `FormData` to store this data? It's an acceptable pattern in React to send data back up to a parent component?

Comment: I'm not sure i fully get how can you use the key property here... I'd store the `fieldStates` in the `FormData` state and define the `handleInputChange` handler in the `FormData` that i'd pass to Input components and in this handler I'd update the common `fieldStates` state. Sorry I can not give a more detailed example, gotta run now! If i could be of help, when Im back, I'd love to explain in more detail.

Comment: No worries, thanks. I'm newish to React so still figuring out some of these concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so a parent of the `Input` will handle the state and validations.
You can conditionally invoke the "validator" of the `surname` property or any other property only if it exists and do a convention with yourself that a validate method will get the name of: `propertNameValidator` .
So for example when you do the loop over the inputs, you could check if there is 
a validate method named `surnameValidator` and invoke it against the `hidden` prop that you will pass the `Input`, if it is not exists then just pass `false`.

Here is a small example with your code:

```js
// Field data
const fieldData = [
  {
    type: "text",
    label: "First",
    name: "first",
    placeholder: "Enter first name",
    hidden: false
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    label: "Surname",
    name: "surname",
    placeholder: "Enter surname",
    hidden: true
  }
];

// Get form data
class FormData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: props.data.map(el => ({...el, value: ''})) // add the value property
    };
  }

  onInputChange = (inputId, value) => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    const nextState = items.map((item) => {
      if (inputId !== item.name) return item;
      return {
        ...item,
        value,
      }
    });
    this.setState({ items: nextState });
  }

  surnameValidator = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    const nameElement = items.find(item => item.name === 'first');
    return nameElement && nameElement.value.length >= 5
  }

  render() {
    let els = this.state.items;

    return (
      <div>
        {
          els.map((el, i) => {
            const validator = this[`${el.name}Validator`];
            return (
              <Input
                key={i}
                {...el}
                inputId={el.name}
                hidden={validator ? !validator() : el.hidden}
                onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Input builder
class Input extends React.Component {

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { inputId, onInputChange } = this.props;
    onInputChange(inputId, target.value);
  }

  render() {
    // Element attributes
    const { type, label, name, placeholder, hidden, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          hidden ? '' : (
            <div>
              {label ? <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label> : null}
              <input
                type={type}
                name={name}
                placeholder={placeholder || null}
                value={value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// App
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Show/Hide test</h1>
        <p>
          What we want here is the surname to appear when firstname has a value
          (say, it has 5 characters) and hide surname when firstname doesn't.
        </p>
        <FormData data={fieldData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <form>
    <App />
  </form>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you already created the element and you just want to hide / show it, then you can conditionally add or remove a CSS `class` that hides it.

```
<input className={`${!isValid && 'hide'}`} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but like @raksheetbhat I'm not looking to create a new input element in the render, I'm looking to unhide an element that was already created. If you look at the demo on codepen, surname has not been rendered as it's set to hidden, but I want it to render when first name has been created.

Comment: My guess here is the parent component `FormData` needs to manage the show/hide state for each generated element.

Comment: OK now i understand your goal, a component can't nor should control the state of its siblings. you can list the state up and let the parent control the children's state. this is  done all the time. i will post an example

Comment: That would be great, thank you! Even better if you could fork my example. I'm pretty new to React so it's hard replicating some examples.

https://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/qpmWVX?editors=1010

Comment: @PaulRedmond check my edited answer, i hope this can be a good starting point

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. Very nice, I get the concept now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, what you want is to conditionally show or hide an input element. See if this helps.

```
render() {
      // Element attributes
      const {type, label, name, placeholder, hidden} = this.props.params;
      const isValid = this.state.valid === true ? <span>Valid! Should show Surname field.</span> : <span>Not valid. Should hide Surname field.</span>;

      if (!hidden) {
        return (
        <div>
            {label ? <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label> : null}
            <input
                type={type}
                name={name}
                placeholder={placeholder || null}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            {this.state.valid && <input placeholder="add surname" />}
        </div>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yes and no. I do want to show a new field, but one already created, not one created within the render. Take a look at the demo, thanks!

Comment: @PaulRedmond It's unclear why you want to create a component outside of render. You can always set CSS classes (or the hidden property) that will just hide elements visually

Comment: What I meant is that I don't want to create a new input like in the answer above. The Input component is a template to generate elements from an array of data. I want one of these generated elements to control another's show/hide. That's the challenge.